ImportError: cannot import name 'is_sparse_any' from 'torch._subclasses.meta_utils' in PyTorch
I am encountering an import error while trying to define and train a Seq2Seq model using PyTorch. Below is the code snippet I am working with:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import TransformerEncoderLayer, TransformerDecoderLayer

class Seq2Seq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder(config)
        self.decoder = decoder(config)
        
    def forward(self, src, tgt):
        encoder_output = self.encoder(src)
        decoder_output = self.decoder(encoder_output, tgt)
        return decoder_output

model = Seq2Seq(TransformerEncoderLayer, TransformerDecoderLayer, config)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

However, when I run this code, I get the following error at the last line:
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_sparse_any' from 'torch._subclasses.meta_utils'

What I've Tried:
Checked the import statements to ensure they are correct.
Verified that my PyTorch installation is up-to-date.
Searched online for similar issues but couldn't find a clear solution.
How can I resolve the
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_sparse_any' from 'torch._subclasses.meta_utils' error?

Is it related to an issue with my environment variables or a bug in the PyTorch version I am using?
Additional Information:
I have verified that torch is correctly installed by running other basic PyTorch scripts.
This error appears to be related to the environment setup, but I am not sure how to fix it.
Thank you for your help!

I dont think there is any issue with your code


Can you mention the Pytorch version that you are using
Can you also run this piece of code in a new session


tnx. I can run this code in a new session
(torch version is '2.3.1+cpu')
